# RabbitMQ with stomp adapter via web

Tags: javascript, rabbitmq, stomp

I've just enabled stomp plugin in my rabbitmq server.

I've been trying all day to run this examples https://github.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-web-stomp-examples (and others) and I always get:

"Opening Web Socket..."
I receive the request to connect in my server (I can see it in rabbit logs)

And after a while the client disconnects saying:

```
"Whoops! Lost connection to http://localhost:61613/stomp"
```

note: I've tried to subscribe to a queue through **telnet** and everything works great but not with Sockjs.

1) Can anyone help me?

2) I notice that in every examples they always add /stomp to url. Why is that? Do i have to configure something special on the rabbit stomp adapter or is the way like the plugin is done?

I've installed the plugin using this "tutorial": 
http://www.rabbitmq.com/stomp.html

basically i run this command: rabbitmq-plugins enable rabbitmq_stomp

3) In this example i tried to replace http:// for ws:// but the answer was exactly the same but more quickly to answer "the lost connection". I noticed too in firebug console that the url that it is trying to connect is: `http://localhost:61613/stomp/info` (or `http://localhost:61613/info` or ws://localhost:61613/info or ws://localhost:61613/stomp/info depending the given url)

4) In other example it happened something strange. If i let the http the answer of "lost connection" appears. If i change it to ws it starts to give me cross domain problems.

I would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer is:

- You have to install rabbitmq_web_stomp plugin too

  Follow this link:

  http://www.rabbitmq.com/blog/2012/05/14/introducing-rabbitmq-web-stomp/

I had to upgrade to erlang R14B04 too;
When you compile the rabbitmq-web-stomp it generates some files in dist directory. Then you have to copy that to rabbitmq plugins directory (/usr/lib/rabbitmq/lib/rabbitmq_server-2.8.4/plugins).

note: Some of that generated files are already in plugins directory. I had to replace all of them to make all working.

Best Regards,

Eduardo